# null reference exception in unity5 when gameobject destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to build a game. I have an enemy AI that uses the player's position to track and move.But i get a null reference exception when player dies.Can anybody help ?
I have a game controller script and a script for the player's health.I have no issues in these.But the game immediately gives an exception from the enemy AI script even after trying to load a level.I compared the gameobject with null.But doesn't look like its working. Here is what i compared

```
if(object.Equals(Target, null)) // doesn't compare 
Application.LoadLevel("menu");
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Are you Destroying Player object after die? if yes, after Destroy(player) your gameobject will remove and you can't access it . so you get Null Reference Exception.

Comment: Yes.I destroy the player in code.Should I re-spawn the player instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I compared the gameobject with null if(object.Equals(Target, null))

I was able to replicate that problem. Your `if(object.Equals(Target, null))` is not doing what you think it is. To check if object is `null` before using it, simply use

```
if (Target != null)
  //your code
```

Comment: Thanks.:) Its perfect now

Comment: Also the short version is handy, 
`if (Target) 
\\ your code`

Comment: @mgear I encourage new  programmers to go with `if (object != null)`. This is the way it works in C#. The short hand version is slower. It uses a custom Unity operator function to check that and will make new programmers try it in a normal C# app causing other problems.  It may also be removed by Unity in the future. Please take some time and read this http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/

Comment: @Programmer thanks for the info, and had not seen that link before!